# Keeping ElasticSearch in sync with updates through Doctrine

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, doctrine-orm, foselasticabundle

We're using FOSElasticaBundle for integration between Doctrine and ElasticSearch. 
We have a lot of fields indexed in ES. When updating one of the mapped entities directly FOSElasticaBundle makes sure the changes are reflected in ES.
But for cases where only a relationship is updated the changes are not reflected in ES.

Lets say we have the following simple entity structure:
Movie has many-to-one Genre (but cannot resolve Movies from Genre)
Movie has a field title
Genre has a field name

There is an ES index for movies. Both the movie title and genre name are indexed for searching.

When changing the movie directly the changes are synced.
But when the name of the genre is changed, the changes are not reflected in ES.

This is a quite trivial case, but in our case there are many relationships to consider and most of them are indirect relationships. (e.g. Movie -> Role -> Actor)
We've realized that checking for each possible relationship and forcing to index this related entity again is to much work.

We've looked at resolving Doctrine's ClassMetaData to find the path to our indexed type, creating a query for retrieving the indexed entities and persisting them again in ES. However this was to complex because of circular dependencies.
We've also found the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/Nightbr/ddb586394d95877dde8ed7445c51d973) but it only seems to solve direct relationships and requires the updated entity to also be mapped the other way round.

Is there a way to resolve the indexed entities when a (indirect) relationship is updated? It does not matter that if there are some false positives, but we cannot sync the whole index after any entity has changed. We're also open to other solutions not using the Doctrine mapping.

Comment: IMHO you need to fire an event such as GenreChanged and build a background task which specially designed to handle this event. In that task I would collect the identifiers of Movies which needs to be updated using raw SQL, retrieve them using entity manager and reindex in batches. Unfortunately this kind of requirement is out of the scope of bundles/orm's you use and not different than finding and invalidating cached domain objects due to a change. Naming and cache invalidation are always hard.

Comment: Ok, thanks. We were afraid of that. Currently all our relationships filters using ES so this would be to many events to manage. Our second use case would indeed have been to use the same logic for our cache invalidation.

We'll go back to the drawing board and see if we can use the ORM for most of the filtering which would not require so much manual updating of ES.